# How to connect to sqlite3 with red

Tags: sqlite, red

I have tried loading two sqlite libraries mentioned on the red website, however they both are rebol based and give "invalid issue" errors such as:

```
*** Syntax Error: invalid issue! at "^-^-^-#[datatype! integer!]^-[*bind-int (sid"
*** Where: do
*** Stack: do-file expand-directives load
```

Would like to fetch data from an sqlite store and update the same from red.

edit: I've managed to use `call/output` to call the sqlite3 executable, but don't know if there are better ways to do this.

```
files: ""
call/output {sqlite3 test.sqlite "select bookid, title from books order by rowid desc limit 10"} files
rows: split files "^/"
```

Each row then needs to be split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case interpreter choked on a so-called *construction syntax* `#[...]`, which is supported only partially in Red at this point.

Moreso, usage of SQLite3 bindings (and any I/O-oriented library) requires a `port!` datatype implementation, which will come only in 0.7.0 release. In the meantime, `call` should cover you well, even if it looks like an ad-hoc solution.

Comment: Small correction, `port!` datatype will come in 0.7.0.

Comment: @endo64 my mistake, I've misinterpret the change in roadmap. I thought that full I/O have substituted Android support, which was planned on 0.6.5 before; turns out Android was pushed to 0.7.1, and I/O support indeed stayed on 0.7.0.